# search for hospital near a location using Google Maps API v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

How to search for a hospital near a location (by city, state, zip, address) using Google maps API V3.

Yahoo has a pretty good rest based web service where we can create a NSUrl object with this url (http://local.yahooapis.com/LocalSearchService/V2/localSearch?appid=myappid&query=hospital&zip=10301) and pass it to a NSParser which will return all the hospitals near that zip.

How can we do the something like this using google api?? We have to use google api.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Google Places API-- it's fairly recent but should do exactly what you're looking for: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html